# Send two variables to js via php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have

```
$userPostsInt = array("22", "45", "56");
```

I am receiving via ajax an id:

```
$post_id = $_POST['id'];
```

Then on front end I click and send an ID and I need to check if:

```
 1. the clicked ID is in the array
 2. if the array count is <= 2 if not do something
```

So I try:

```
$totSaved = array();
$userPostsInt = array("22", "45", "56");
$count = count($userPostsInt);
if($count<2) {
  foreach($userPostsInt as $key=>$post){ 
    if( $post == $post_id ) { 
      foreach($userPostsInt as $idInt){ 
        array_push($totSaved, $idInt);
      }
      echo json_encode($count);
    }
  }
} else {
  echo json_encode($count); 
}
```

Then on ajax success I do:

```
success: function(data) {
    var received = true;
    if(received) {
        if(data < 2) {
            do_something
        } else {
            do_something
        }
    } else {
        do_something else
    }
}
```

How can I send 2 variable on `echo json_encode($count);` in order to do a double check for **"is ID in the array? Is the array less than 2?"** or is it there another way I'm missing?

Comment: what i can suggest you that use `in_array()` instead of `foreach()` to check ajax given values lies in your array or not

Comment: Just pass an array e.g. `echo json_encode(array('found' => $found, 'count' => $count));` and you will get an object in your success code and you can access the values via `data.found` and `data.count` (note you need to specify `dataType: json` or parse the data)

Comment: @Nick yes exactly what I was trying to do but not fond of PHP, so that's how we send 2 vars right?

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie mind to post a solution answer based on that?

Comment: @Nick I tried dataType: json, and I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: json is not defined` and did `echo json_encode(array('found' => "yes", 'count' => $count));` I have zero ids saved

Comment: in your code `if($count<2)` will never be true since `$count` is always 3, also `json_encode` does not return several values, it will always return one single JSON-like string, which you could structure your way and split client-side to make the checks you want

Comment: @Scaramouche do you mind to place an answer?

Comment: @rob.m sorry, wrote the comment in a hurry, it should have been `dataType: "json"`. But I see you have a working solution now anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simple way to do is use `in_array()` along with array output:

```
$totSaved = array();
$userPostsInt = array("22", "45", "56");
$count = count($userPostsInt);

if(in_array($post_id,$userPostsInt)){
    echo json_encode(array('found'=>'yes','count'=>$count)); 
}else{
    $totSaved[] = $post_id;//add new value for next time checks
    echo json_encode(array('found'=>'no','count'=>$count)); 
}
```

Comment: bingo! Thanks a lot